# Fragment restore after rotate: onDetach called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm facing an issue that is driving me crazy. I have an application based on the NavigationDrawer that AndroidStudio setups.

My MainActivity class has this method in which I instance the Fragments:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Log.i(this.toString(), "onNavigationDrawerItemSelected() -> Instance new Fragment");

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

My MapFragment, overrides this methods for data restoring:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(this.toString(), "onActivityCreated savedInstanceState -> " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "NULL" : "DATA"));

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // TODO: Restore markers, polylines, etc
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.i(this.toString(), "onSaveInstanceState()");

    // Saves the data
    outState.putParcelableArray("lineas", mLineas);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

The problem is, when I rotate the device, the system is calling onDetach twice. The first time, onActivityCreated receives the bundle OK, but the second time, it is null, causing that the Fragment instance has no restored data. Here is my logcat:

```
02-12 19:19:34.866  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{4285f5a0 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onSaveInstanceState()
02-12 19:19:34.947  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{4285f5a0 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onDetach()
02-12 19:19:35.047  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/com.pinard.bustracer.MainActivity@42be59a0﹕ onCreate savedInstanceState -> DATA
02-12 19:19:35.047  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42be7448 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onAttach()
02-12 19:19:35.047  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42be7448 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onCreate savedInstanceState -> DATA
02-12 19:19:35.067  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/com.pinard.bustracer.MainActivity@42be59a0﹕ onNavigationDrawerItemSelected() -> Instance new Fragment
02-12 19:19:35.087  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42be7448 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onCreateView savedInstanceState -> DATA
02-12 19:19:35.127  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42be7448 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onActivityCreated savedInstanceState -> DATA
02-12 19:19:35.147  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42be7448 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onDetach()
02-12 19:19:35.147  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42c570b8 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onAttach()
02-12 19:19:35.147  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42c570b8 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onCreate savedInstanceState -> NULL
02-12 19:19:35.147  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42c570b8 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onCreateView savedInstanceState -> NULL
02-12 19:19:35.157  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42c570b8 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onActivityCreated savedInstanceState -> NULL
02-12 19:19:35.157  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42c570b8 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onStart()
02-12 19:19:35.757  11270-11270/com.pinard.bustracer I/MapFragment{42c570b8 #1 id=0x7f080040}﹕ onResume()
```

I have read a lot of stuff here in SO, but can't figure out a solution.

What am I missing? Can you point me in some direction?

Comment: Instead of `Fragment` or `MainActivity` for your logs, could you use `this.toString()`? That way I can tell which fragment is actually being created and destroyed.

Comment: @bclymer I've posted an edit of the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    string s;
    if(position == 0)
    {
    s = MapFragment.Tag;
    }
    else
    {
    s = SettingsFragment.TAg;
    }
    Fragment fragment;
    fargment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(s);

    if(null == fragment)
    {
    string tag = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MapFragment();
    tag = MapFragment.Tag;
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    tag = SettingsFragment.Tag;
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new MapFragment();
    tag = MapFragment.Tag;
                break;
        }
    }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
                .commit();

// THe code is not optimised by gives u idea what u need to do. the tags are static methods that u need to add to ur settings and map fragment
```

Comment: `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(s)` is always returning null. In any case I don't understand when do you set the tag to the fragment instance, so the fragmentManager can find it.

Comment: Ok I'll figure out, you miss the `tag` parameter in the `replace`... I'll fix it for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `Bundle` is null is because you're creating a `new` `MapFragment`. Note in your logs the first `MapFragment` is at `42be7448` and the second is at `42c570b8`.

To keep your instance state bundle around, you need to keep your `MapFragment` instance around. Consider this

```
// Class level
private MapFragment mMapFragment;
private SettingsFragment mSettingsFragment;

Fragment fragment;
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = mMapFragment == null ? new MapFragment() : mMapFragment;
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = mSettingsFragment == null ? new SettingsFragment() : mSettingsFragment;
        break;
    default:
        fragment = mMapFragment == null ? new MapFragment() : mMapFragment;
        break;
}
```

That will cache your fragments and allow states to carry over.

I also think there is a problem with your Activity recreating itself. `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` is called when you set the callback, so what you're seeing is.

1) Your Fragment gets destroyed.

2) Your Activity gets destroyed.

3) Your Activity gets recreated.

4) Your Fragment gets a new instance created. <-- That's what you need to stop.

Comment: The log looks similar, with different memory adresses for `MapFragment`

Comment: @PulkitSethi How I do that?

Comment: I added a little more detail about what I think might be going on @AgustinMeriles, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Yes, the Activity is recreating, so the mFragments instances are lost. I have to go for the `tag` solution. Thank you very much anyway!